# PHP Amazon API Multiple Function Variables

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I'm using the Amazon API PHP library to download reports from our Seller Central account.

There is an API call called "UpdateReportAcknowledgements" which uses `MarketplaceWebService_Model_UpdateReportAcknowledgementsRequest` from the library. This class has a `setReportIdList` method which takes and instance of `MarketplaceWebService_Model_IdList` as a parameter. The `MarketplaceWebService_Model_IdList` class has a method called `withId`, and this is where I need help.

The `withId` method has these comments in the library:

```
/**
 * Sets single or multiple values of Id list via variable number of arguments. 
 * For example, to set the list with two elements, simply pass two values as arguments to this function
 * <code>withId($id1, $id2)</code>
 */
```

So it accepts multiple id variables (and then uses `func_get_args()` within the function). I'm sure accepting an array would be easier (for me) but I don't really want to be updating Amazons library code.

I have an `array()` containing 3 ids (stored as strings).

How do I take my array and turn it into 3 argument variables for the `withId` method..?

**UPDATE**
My array has 3 ids at the moment, but that might change and be 1, or 6 or 15, or any other number. The number of ids will change each time the method is called.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question correctly. Can't you just do: `withId($array[0], $array[1], $array[2])`?

Comment: Sorry about that... I have 3 ids in my array this time, but it could be 1, or 8 or 15 next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot test it at the moment but I think, you can use `call_user_func_array`, see this [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php).

So in your case that would be:

```
call_user_func_array(array($instanceToCallOn, 'withId'), $myArray);
```

There is also the possibility of using [reflection](http://php.net/reflectionfunction.invokeargs) since PHP 5.1:

```
$myReflection = new ReflectionMethod('MarketplaceWebService_Model_IdList', 'withId');
$myReflection->invokeArgs($instanceToCallOn, $myArray);
```

Comment: I used `call_user_func_array()` and seems to be working nicely... Thanks!